# RDP and run command on remote windows machine using command line

Tags: cmd, rdp, mstsc

I have gone through various links on SO regarding RDP to a windows machine but still can't understand how to execute for test, `ipconfig` command on remote machine and gather the results in a text file.

I can't get beyond `Mstsc` which creates the gui and asks for password and username.

Comment: Your best choice is to use `Invoke-Command` in `PowerShell`. If the `Invoke-Command` statement you create does not work, then copy it into a question here in order to ask.

Comment: Can you please point me to some reference code?

Comment: Complete with examples. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command?view=powershell-5.1